# Как закрыть окно браузера в странице, написанной на ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Я пробовал закрыть окно браузера с помощью страницы javascript кода `windows.close()`. Но данная команда не срабатывает. Каким образом можно закрыть окно браузера?

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант подходит?

```
Dim strScript As String = " " & _
    "var parentwin = window.self; " & _
    "parentwin.opener = window.self; " & _
    "parentwin.close(); "

    ' Закрываем окно
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "_CLOSE_", "<script language='javascript'>" + strScript + "</script>", False)
```

[Закрыть окно без пользователя?](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=638605)